# How can I tell which version of Android tools is used by IntelliJ if an Android project is not Maven or Gradle-based

Tags: android, intellij-idea, build

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.2 Ultimate for Android development.  Where in the IDE can I find the version of Android SDK build tools and platform tools it uses to build an Android project that's not a Gradle or Maven project?  (Does that mean IntelliJ is using Ant to build?)

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Gradle and try building the project again from the IntelliJ. If it doesn't work, it's probably using Gradle then, so then type `gradle -v` or `gradle --version` from the command line.

If it still works after you've uninstalled Gradle, it's probably using Ant I suppose. If you want to find out more, start the SDK manager from IntelliJ. At the top of the window of your sdk manager should be the path to the Android SDK IntelliJ is using.

Then look in the `platform-tools/` folder or the `tools/` folder. And type `ant -version` from the command line if you want to know the version of ant you're using.

Comment: Great to know! Any idea on how to select an specific version of the tools?

Comment: @JuanPabloMendezNogales, Sorry. I don't know.